# How can i output values using a pointer in C++?

Tags: c++

I have the following:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;


 int main() {
   string food = "Pie";  
   string ptr = &food;  
   cout << food << "\n";
   cout << &food << "\n";
   cout << ptr << "\n";
 return 0;
}
```

i would of expected output as
Pizza
0x
0x

but get error:

```
 error: conversion from ‘std::string*’
```

any reason whats wrong ?

Comment: Post the full error message.

Comment: In function ‘int main()’:
error: conversion from ‘std::string*’ {aka ‘std::string<char>*’} to non-scalar type ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::string<char>’} requested
   string ptr = &food;

Comment: Did you mean to write `std::string * ptr = &food;`?

Comment: ah that worked , yes must of missed it ..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you expect to see Pizza 0x 0x?

If you want to create a pointer to a string object, you can use the address-of operator with the string object(which is what I am assuming you're trying to do), you can do it like this.

```
string food = "Pie";
string* ptr = &food;
```

The & symbol is to create a pointer while the * is for declarations and dereferencing.

Then you can do something like this

```
cout << *ptr << "\n"; // Output: Pie
cout << ptr->size() << "\n"; // Output: 3 which is the number of characters 
stored in food
```